# C++ [] operator overload problem

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm still new to C++ so I daily run into new problems.

Today came the [] operator's turn:

I'm making myself a new generic List class because I don't really like the std's one. I'm trying to give it the warm and fuzzy look of the C#'s Collections.Generic List, so I do want to be able to access elements by index. To cut to the chase:

Extract from the template:

```
T& operator[](int offset)
    {
        int translateVal = offset - cursorPos;

        MoveCursor(translateVal);

        return cursor->value;
    }

    const T& operator[](int offset) const
    {
        int translateVal = offset - cursorPos;

        MoveCursor(translateVal);

        return cursor->value;
    }
```

That's the code for the operators. The template uses "template", so as far as I saw on some tutorials, that's the correct way to do operator overloading.

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to access by index, e.g.:

```
Collections::List<int> *myList;
myList = new Collections::List<int>();
myList->SetCapacity(11);
myList->Add(4);
myList->Add(10);
int a = myList[0];
```

I get the

```
    no suitable conversion function from "Collections::List<int>" to "int" exists
```

error, referring to the "int a = myList[0]" line. Basically "myList[0]" type's is still "Collections::List", although it should have been just int. How Come?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `myList` is a pointer `myList[0]` doesn't invoke `operator[]`, it returns `Collections::List<int>*`. What you want is `(*myList)[0]`. Or better still, `Collections::List<int>& myRef = *myList;` and then use `myRef[0]` (Other option is not allocate the memory for `myList` on the heap, you can create it on stack using `Collections::List<int> myList` and then use `.` operator on it).

Comment: Good point actually. In my case I just changed the list declaration, cutting out the pointer part. That was it, thanks!

Comment: @cantrem: in C++, you should not use allocation with `new` if you can avoid it. Since there is no garbage collector, you will have to manually `delete` those objects, which can became quite a pain when your project starts growing and you always have to know who "owns" the object and is responsible for deleting it.

Comment: Yes and no. Although not set by default, there are a couple of smart pointers out there to help you take out the garbage.

Answer (score 2):

myList has type *pointer to List*, not List. In the case where an expression of pointer type is followed by an integral value enclosed in square brackets, (such as myList[0]), the result is identical to "add 0 to the pointer value and *dereference* it". The result of adding 0 to the address of the list and dereferencing it simply yields the list.

It is common for programmers used to C# and Java to overuse C++ *new*. In the posted example it is better to use `Collections::List<int> myList;` and the `.` operator instead of `->`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. When I wrote that code I didn't actually stop to think about it (yes, I'm still used to the "everything is a pointer" world of C#). I just assumed that "well, I have a class object here, all the operators/functions should work the way I implemented them, so it has to be something wrong with the operator overloading".

Answer (score 0):

Good that you want to learn C++ and practise writing your own collections but your logic is probably flawed.

`std::vector` and `std::deque` already allow constant-time random access. `std::deque` is more like a list in that it allows constant-time insertion and removal at either end and does not invalidate references or iterators due to insertions.

You also seem to be mixing your collection with its iterator into one class, so that a collection contains a current position. I am pretty certain C# collections are not implemented that way.

Finally I would imagine your MoveCursor command is O(N) which means you do not really have random-access at all.

If you want fast random access and insertion time the best you can manage is O(log N) by using a tree structure, with each node on the tree indicating the number of elements in each branch below it. Thus you can find the nth element recursing down the right path. Insertion is also O(log N) as you have to recurse up the tree modifying the counts, and you will of course have to regularly balance the tree.